# Using Angular, Kendo, bootstrap 3 components

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm evaluating Kendo with Angular and Bootstrap 3, fairly new in javascript land. Is there a preferred way as to use which components where? I know you can mix and match, but that seems messy. Does anyone have any basic guidelines or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different integration demos on the **[Kendo Labs](http://labs.kendoui.com/)** site which should bring you the idea when it comes to integration with third party libraries. [**Here**](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo) is link to the Angular demo on GitHub.