# Angular-Kendo + Bootstrap Integration?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-kendo

I am looking for the demo/examples where we have support for the angular-kendo and bootstrap together. I went through the kendo labs also but I was not able to find anything useful regarding the angular-kendo and bootstrap integration.

I checked the responses of the question : [Using Angular, Kendo, bootstrap 3 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666148/using-angular-kendo-bootstrap-3-components).

Anything more specific would definitely help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link that shows kendo and bootstrap working together. I personally used this demo to learn a plenty about kendo ui.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, not sure if it's what you wanted, but I recently created a boilerplate project using requires + angular + angular/ui-bootstrap + angular-kendo-ui + angular/ui-router.

I have a header bar using the bootswatch cosmo theme of bootstrap. The default view page have some alerts on it just for demonstration purposes. View3 currently have a kendo drop down list also just for demonstration purpose.

I plan to continue develop it into a showcase of anuglar-kendo-ui, but at least the project structure is already setup and you can do whatever you want with it.

Here is the git: https://github.com/davidiamyou/kendo-angular-seed

Let me know:)